# Probleme of Sticky Footer with navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a little problem when i  try to minimize the page and make it small

all is well except that the navbar control moves up and i don't understand where is the problem

Here is the code and it is the same in several tutorial :

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom"> 
    <div class="navbar-inner">
       <div class="container">
            <p class="navbar-text pull-left">
               Site Realiser par Hoffmannew
            </p>
            <a href="http://youtube.com" class="navbar-btn btn-danger btn pull-right" >Suiver Nous sur Youtube</a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and also the screenshot :

[image]

Comment: It's difficult to know without CSS file or more code. Can you post more information please? ;)

Comment: CSS file is the same file in http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Comment: but tell me please what you want i will press Ctrl+F and search and after copy past to here

Comment: I'll put your code in [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2cvbB/) and tried and it seems to work

Comment: I forget i am so sorry i forget the file css bootstrap-responsive.min.css its  the cause of this problem i want an other file bootstrap-responsive.min.css or what i should to modify in this file

Comment: its solved by deleting this file thank you very mush

Comment: I'm glad you've been able to solve